# Git: turn a directory with repos into a repo with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm developing my project in a directory "software". The project is divided into subdirectories:

```
software
  |
  +-- common_forms
  |     +-- .git
  +-- common_utils
  |     +-- .git
  +-- gui_app
  |     +-- .git
  + ...
  ... and so on.
```

Each subdirectory is a git repo; the master directory "software" is not a repo, just a root for the repos.

Now I want to turn the master directory "software" into a repo, and include those repositories as master repo's submodules. How can I do it not destroying the existing structure of directories and repos?

Comment: Just cd into software and say git init?

Comment: or have a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: @matt, and after "git init" will all the subdirectories magically become submodules of "software" repo?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add one word—sort of redundant, but important for emphasis—here:

> Each subdirectory is **already** a git repo; the master directory "software" is not a repo, just a root for the repos.

In this case, just enter the `software` directory, run `git init` to create a `.git` directory / repository with this as its top level working tree, and use `git submodule add` for each of the various submodules.  See [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for specifics of `git submodule add`.  Then `git add` the `.gitmodules` file and commit, to make the initial commit.

Note that the *repository* argument to each `git submodule add` command can be the same as the `path` argument.  This affects what winds up in the `.gitmodules` file, which—once you make a commit in the superproject you've just created—is now available for *future* clones of this superproject.

That is, in the future, someone—let's give him or her a name, e.g., Pat—will run:

```
git clone $URL [<path>]
```

to clone the submodule from some URL (for now I'm assuming it's in `$URL`, though Pat might type in a literal string rather than use a variable).  Then Pat will `cd` into the clone and run, e.g., `git submodule update --init`.

Pat's clone here needs to have instructions for `git submodule init` or `git submodule update --init`.  These instructions tell Git what all the submodules are and how to `git clone` each one.  That is, rather than Pat having to, now, run one `git clone` for each submodule, Pat's `git submodule update --init` allows Pat's Git to read, from the `.gitmodules` file, the URLs and path names needed for each of *these* `git clone` operations.

A path-relative pseudo-URL, such as `./common_forms`, turns into a URL-relative URL.  That is, since Pat cloned `$URL` to make the superproject, the `.gitmodules` URL `./common_forms` turns into the URL `${URL}/common_forms`.  If this is the right URL, everything is good.

On the other hand, suppose you plan to push the superproject to `host1.example.com/supers/superproj.git` but all the *submodules* will live at URLs like `host2.example.com/subs/common_forms.git`.  Then when you create the `.gitmodules` file—or before committing it, at least—you should make sure that the URL that will be stored *in* the `.gitmodules` file is `host2.example.com/subs/common_forms` or `host2.example.com/subs/common_forms.git`.  That way Pat will still be able to run `git submodule update --init`.

(It makes the most sense to arrange for the repository hosting to mirror the superproject-and-submodule layout, when that is possible, but it's not always possible.)

Comment: thank you for your great explanation. In my question I forget to clarify, that every repo already has its corresponding remote, traditionally named "origin". I tried to add submodules using the relative dir's paths, but on the remote repos' website the URLs of submodules become broken: the links results in 404 error. Then I used the remote URLs of the subprojects repos. All is OK in this case.